# Error with npm: NPM Does not support NodeJS v14.11.0

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Everytime I run npm install, I keep getting the following error with 14.11.0 node and 6.14.8 npm installed:

npm does not support Node.js v14.11.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.

Comment: Have you tried updating Node?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights  yes i have

Comment: How did you install it? With Homebrew or a different way?

Comment: And could you post the full error?